# Django admin filter a foreign field based on another field value

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

In my django app, in admin panel, when i go to add/edit form for my table i have two foreign key columns (combo), main_id and Test_id.

I would to filter the result contained in test_id field based on previews choice in main_id field selection.

In my admin.py I try:

```
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "test_id":
        kwargs["queryset"] = temp_case.objects.filter(main_id = <here i need the value selected on main_id combo>)
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

but I don't know what i have to write in ''.

I try main_id__id, or main_id.id but was not correct.

How can I retrieve the value of selection in main_id combo and pass it to my method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Django Smart Selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) It has feature called [Grouped Selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#grouped-selects)

Quote from Readme:

> If you have the following model:
>
> ```
> class Country(models.Model):
>     continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
>
> class Location(models.Model):
>     continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
>     country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
> ```
>
> And you want to group countries by their continent in the HTML select
>   list, you can use a GroupedForeignKey:
>
> ```
> from smart_selects.db_fields import GroupedForeignKey
>
> class Location(models.Model):
>     continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
>     country = GroupedForeignKey(Country, "continent")
> ```